# Fail Silently for a Nuget Package?

Tags: .net-6.0, software-design

I have a nuget package that does some stuff. In particular this one I call a `HttpService` here is the interface:

```
public interface IHttpService
{
    Task<object> DeleteAsync(..);
    Task<object> GetAsync(..);
    Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync(...);
    Task<object> PatchAsync(...);
    Task<object> PostAsync(..);
    Task<object> PutAsync(..);
}
```

So, let's say an operation fails, say `PatchAsync` should I return `null` or should I `throw new Exception(...` what is the rule of thumb when my service fails. Specifically in my case, let's say we have this HttpService thing and it should make httpRequests based of some inputs. Cool.

Let's say it fails before actually making the request. Like, some preceding step before: `var httpRequestResponse = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);`

Ok. So what is the rule. Idk, anything fails, and I check and say:

```
if(someVariable != null){
   // everything is ok, 
   HappyPath();
}

return null;// ???
or
throw new Exception("Somthing went wrong"); // ???
```

```
public async Task<object> PatchAsync(string url, 
                                        object data, 
                                        string accessToken, 
                                        string userName, 
                                        Dictionary<string, string>? requestHeadersDictionary = null)
    {
        var serializedPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        var jsonPatchDocument = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonPatchDocument>(serializedPayload);

        if(jsonPatchDocument != null)
        {
            return await PatchAsync(url, jsonPatchDocument, accessToken, userName, requestHeadersDictionary);
        }
        
        return null;
        // TODO: How should I handle this? Fail silently? ... or
        // return new Exception("Error with payload");
    }
```

What should the consumer expect to happen? If you had built some app, and want to use this quick tool to handle all Http stuff, and something fails and its not the actual http request, what would you expect??? `null` or and `Exception` being thrown?

Comment: In languages that have exceptions, such as C#, the expected way to communicate errors is by throwing exceptions.

Comment: There is strict rule known as **samurai's principle** - If method can't do its work it was created for - it throws exception, as samurai kills himself when his master dies. But there are exceptions, it depends on level of abstraction. Principle primarilly works in domain context. But there are tradeoffs, so behavior may vary, you should see the whole picture, and decide then.